# why does the values repeat?

Tags: java, string, hashmap

The problem is in the output the word clever is added 2 times. Can you please tell me why duplicate values with the same key are being added twice. Thanks in advance for your help!

```
package HashMap;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;

public class Thesaurus {
    HashMap<String, String> words =new HashMap<String, String>();

    public void add(String x,String y)
    {
        if (!words.containsKey(x))
            words.put(x, y);
        else if (!words.containsValue(y))
            words.put(x, words.get(x) + " " + y + " ");
    }
    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println(words);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thesaurus tc = new Thesaurus();
        tc.add("large", "big");
        tc.add("large", "humoungus");
        tc.add("large", "bulky");
        tc.add("large", "broad");
        tc.add("large", "heavy");
        tc.add("smart", "astute");
        tc.add("smart", "clever");
        tc.add("smart", "clever");

        tc.display();
    }
}
```

output

```
{smart=astute clever  clever , large=big humoungus  bulky  broad  heavy }
```

Comment: Did you try debugging it step by step?

Answer (score 4):

Your `else if` is the problem. You are checking for `!words.containsValue(y)`, which will check if there is a value `clever`, which there isn't. There only is `astute clever`. That will cause an execution of `words.put(x, words.get(x) + " " + y + " ");`, and consequently, adding of `clever` to the index of `smart`.

Your `add` method can only assure the uniquess of values for single words, not multiple.

You can solve this by redefining your `HashMap` words as `HashMap<string, HashSet<string>>` and using the methods on that class; you'll have to change your `display` method though to print out the elements of the `HashSet`.

Comment: so how should I resolve the problem...how should I override my equals method?

Comment: Overriding the equals method doesn't really help here. You'll want to use an actual data structure to hold the words, and only convert that to an output if you need it. A suitable data structure would be, as detailed in the answer (I added it later), a `HashMap`, where each element can only be present once.

Comment: how would I modify the add method if I make the values a HashSet

Comment: Only if you write the code I'm working on at the moment. And trust me, you don't want to do that.